# Azure Run Python Code

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I run Python code on Azure whenever my cosmos-db is updated.

To get the data from AZURE-COSMOS-DB and run Python with a machine learning module, currently, as per my understanding, Hadoop insight is the better option.

Can anyone advise?

Actually my work is ..

1. Get data from Cosmo-DB
2. Do my analytics thrg Python with ML Module
3. Save to SQL DB -Reason storing sql DB becaz Power BI cant support cosmo DB sostoring in SQL DB and use power BI for visualization

I hope u understand the requirment.

Comment: Hi,any updates now? Any more details about your requirements?

Comment: @jay-gong Thanks for the information. Azure Cosmo-DB trigger function works. KUDU i dont think i can use it. 

Actually my work is .. 

1. Get data from Cosmo-DB
2. Do my analytics thrg Python with ML Module
3. Save to SQL DB - Reason storing sql DB becaz Power BI cant support cosmo DB so storing in SQL DB and use power BI for visualization

I hope u understand requirment.

Comment: Hi,as I know,azure function is a function app. If you want to run the python code in it,you need to install python environment first.Why you think you do not need to use KUDU.

Comment: Thank you for the information .. I am going to work on KUDU i ll update soon. Just a thought how DSVM ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Azure Function Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function).It could be triggered whenever your cosmos-db updated.Please see the [github sample](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/cosmosdb-trigger-cosmosdb-in-binding).

You could install python package in the KUDU,please see this [tutorial](https://blog.powerupcloud.com/running-python-on-azure-functions-time-trigger-external-libraries-71b8bdd4eb7d).

Any concern, please let me know.

Comment: Can't really give advice to install something via kudu, as this implies the OP is using web apps (and we have zero detail on what they're doing). We also don't have any context around their comment about Hadoop (which seems orthogonal to a function trigger). And if this is something significant, that would take the type of horsepower that Hadoop/HDInsight offers, then a Function will likely not work, due to resource and time limits.

Comment: Actually my work is ..

    1. Get data from Cosmo-DB
    2. Do my analytics thrg Python with ML Module
    3. Save to SQL DB -Reason storing sql DB becaz Power BI cant support cosmo DB sostoring in SQL DB and use power BI for visualization

I hope u understand the requirment. can you help me out. KUDU can run ML Modules and main important criteria without any delay

Comment: Thank you for the information .. I am going to work on KUDU i ll update soon. Just a thought how DSVM ?